# Geotargeting via contact IP address - Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions

I'm surprised to find that SFMC doesn't seem to have geotargeting functionality -- most email marketing/marketing automation systems have this, based on the subscriber's IP address when they open emails.

This lets marketers segment based on subscriber location (country, region).

For example, here is some info on this from other systems -- including Pardot:

https://www.pardot.com/blog/auto-append-country-and-state-from-prospect-ip-address-2/
https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/tnt/help/t_Targeting_Based_on_Geography.html
https://nation.marketo.com/docs/DOC-1690
https://mailchimp.com/help/about-geolocation/
https://www.activecampaign.com/blog/geo-location-data-now-available/

**Anyone figure out a way to do this in SFMC?**

Thanks!

Comment: The SFMC tracking pixel is locked down so unless you do extracts, like @DavidDevoy said, you aren't getting much from there. But if you use either a 3rd party service (Litmus, EmailonAcid, etc) or build a home grown pixel you can easily gather this information in real time and send it to SFMC.  You CAN also build this as a pixel that calls a CloudPage to keep it inhouse, but this can get expensive real quick as SFMC charges per view on CPs and that is total views, not unique.

Answer (score 4):

Marketing Cloud does have the option to include "User Agent Information" as part of [Tracking Extracts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_tracking_extract_config.htm&type=5).  This option will append the following columns to the Open and Click extract data:

- IpAddress
- Country
- Region
- City
- Latitude
- Longitude
- MetroCode
- AreaCode
- Browser
- EmailClient
- OperatingSystem
- Device

I'm not aware of any out-of-the-box tools in Marketing Cloud that leverage this data.  But, you can definitely import the tracking data back into Marketing Cloud (or some external system) and build a custom solution which leverages IP address.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that since geolocations scraped from the user agent can be inaccurate, they're not giving their customers a false sense of knowing where their subscribers are. Frankly, if you want good geolocation data, it's better to gather it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to David Devoys answer, it can be worth mentioning, that Web & Mobile analytics also provide this type of insight for identified subscribers. The location from where the tracked  webpage is visited gets stored in IGO_PROFILES data extension, and can be extracted or joined from here.